# shift contents of memory

Tags: memory, copy, byte, shift

I have a structure in C. I need to shift the contents of that structure by n bytes. Now this is just a debugging output of that structure:

```
struct ztc6_ddl_add_subnet_def{
***
<<truncated>>
***
zgate_ip = 0,
zgate = 0,
znetmask_ip = -1,
znetmask = -256,
zif_mtu_ip = 0,
zif_mtu = -1,
zfailover_ip = 8224,
zfailover_type = 8224,
***
<<truncated>>
***
}
```

I want to shift the contents of this structure starting from position "znetmask_ip" by 2 variables ahead.. such that -1 is assigned to "zif_mtu_ip" and so on, and the resulting output is :

```
struct ztc6_ddl_add_subnet_def{
***
<<truncated>>
***
zgate_ip = 0,
zgate = 0,
znetmask_ip = x,
znetmask = x,
zif_mtu_ip = -1,
zif_mtu = -256,
zfailover_ip = 0,
zfailover_type = -1,
***
<<truncated>>
***
}
```

I will copy something in place of 'x' later.
Let it be an intensive operation affecting on performance but is there a simple expression which can do the job?
PS: consider the size of each element to be 1 byte.

Comment: memmove(&ztc.zif_mtu_ip, &ztc.znetmask_ip, sizeof(ztc)-(((char *)&ztc.zif_mtu_ip)-((char *)&ztc))); should do it, assuming ztc is an instance of your structure.  I've probably got extra casts and parentheses in that expression.

Comment: Thanks @garlon4 !! That worked like charm. I totally overlooked this function.